# string of numbers into a numpy list?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to make '1 2 3' into a numpy [1, 2, 3]

I've tried

```
x = '1 2 3'
x = np.fromstring(x, dtype=int, sep=' ')
```

and it works, but is there any other way to do it? Maybe using np.array()? Thanks.

Comment: `np.array('1 2 3'.split(),int)`.  `np.array` expects a list, not a string.  `fromstring` expects a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want you could do `np.array(x.split())`, but the `numpy.fromstring` method will be faster.

Timing for `np.fromstring` on 1000 times x: `45.2 µs ± 4.29 µs`

Timing for `np.array`: `329 µs ± 67.6 µs`

Comment: `np.array` can convert to `int` without the previous `map`.